# Параллельное выполнение нескольких задач

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Я хочу распараллелить выполнение тестов на 2 устройства.

Т.е. у меня есть список с тестами, и я хочу чтобы в функции test_proc по всем устройствам распределил их, test1.py на первое устройство, test2.py на второе и т.д., они выполнились параллельно, если один тест выполнился быстрее, тогда 3 пошёл на него и т.д. по списку с тестами.

Comment: используйте пул потоков/процессов. Как только один из потоков завершит выполнения метода с текущим элементов списка, он берет следующий элемент списка и для него начинает выполнять метод

Comment: Можете ссылку или пример скинуть?

Answer (score 2):

Допустим нам необходимо выполнить метод parse в несколько потоков. На вход метода передается ссылка:

```
def parse(url):
     .....
```

Нам необходимо обработать список ссылок `urls`

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def start_parse(urls):
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
        for _ in executor.map(parse, urls):
            pass
```

Пулы потоков / процессов есть у множества библиотек

Что касательно вашего примера, я бы в качестве urls передал список устройств.
Метод parse был бы у нас общим методов, а список тестов я бы превратил в очередь.

В общем тесте у потока у нас есть одно устройств и мы выбираем из очереди тестов тест, пока эта очередь не будет пуста.

Например:

```
tests = Quque()
devs = [devs1, devs2, devs3]

def parse(dev):
    while tests.qsize > 0:
        test = tests.get() #Получаем тест из очереди.
        ..... Выполняем данный тест для данного устройства

def start_parse(devs):
   with ThreadPoolExecutor(count_thread) as executor:
       for _ in executor.map(parse, devs):
           pass
```

Только в этом случае количество потоков = количеству устройств, иначе какое-либо из устройств не получит тесты.

Можно придумать другие реализации

Comment: Вам нужно их в очередь занести

Comment: А вот в последней функции urls это что? Там ошибка?

Comment: да, опечатался.

Comment: С pool у меня неправильно работает, два теста отправляет на одно устройство, а не параллельно два разных теста, на два разных устройства

Comment: @Alia значит у вас логика не правильная

Comment: Можете подсказать, что не так сделала? Вставила код с pool в вопросе

Comment: @Alia приведите полностью код, с всеми переменными

Comment: привела в задаче

Comment: @Alia во-первых у вас все потоки пытаются прочитать файл, так не должно быть, вы либо используйте блокировки, чтобы только 1 поток читал одновременно, либо вообще храните это все в оперативной памяти

Comment: def func1(name, ip, module):
    print(name, ip, module)
    for i in range(100000):
        print(i)
Проверьте этот код, по отображаемым цифрам видно, что процессоры работают одновременно